# Generate m outcomes of a geometric random variable using the cdf of the random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, geometric-probability

As part of an assignment, I have been asked to write an Octave function that will generate $m$ pseudorandom outcomes of a geometric RV $X$ with parameter $p = 0.55$ in 2 separate ways:

1. Directly using the cdf of the RV
2. Using the fact that the variable is produced using independent Bernoulli experiments.

For 2, my thoughts are:

- create a loop of $m$ iterations
- create an inner loop that repeats until there is a successful trial
- have a counting variable in the inner loop that counts how many failures there are before a success, and store this count for each of the $m$ iterations of the outer loop.

However, I am quite lost with part one, and am struggling to even understand what the question means by "directly using the cdf of the random variable".

**EDIT**

Here is my code for part 1 so far:

```
function x = generate_geometric_cdf(p, m)
  % generate geometric RV X with parameter p, m times using the cdf

  emperical = zeros(1,m);         % allocate array for empirical results of m simulations
  for i = 1:m                     % iterate over m simulations
    u = rand;                     % generate a random number between 0-1
    emperical(i) = geocdf(u, p);  % store the outcome of the geometric distribution at u                 
  end

   x = emperical;

end
```

The `geocdf` function is always returning 0.

**EDIT 2**

`geoinv` is the function I needed, as opposed to `geocdf` which returns the probabibility from the cdf given a value $u$ and parameter $p$. `geoinv` does, as the name suggests, the inverse of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all go and [consult with Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) to see which version of the geometric distribution you will need.

In both cases the cdf will look like the one below. (The exact shape depends on the type and the parameter $p$).

[image]

Now, generate pseudorandom numbers between $0$ and $1$. The figure above shows how to use an actual random number to select a $k$, an outcome of the simulated geometric distribution.

Comment: Nice diagram! And good call on the two versions of the geometric distribution, though I think asking the TA (or hoping for flexible grading) is a better solution.

Comment: @Misha OK. I appreciate (+1) your remark and attempt to help the OP.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now! So I just generate m random numbers in [0, 1], get their k value through the cdf of p = 0.55, but then I am still lost with how to plot the distribution of these m outcomes? What exactly do the values of k represent? Surely I can't just plot the frequency of each value of k occuring in the m outcomes?

Comment: @KOB: The frequency of your resulting integers is given by the pmf (and the cdf). Why would you recalculate (estimate) the known probabilities? Is you goal not to generate random numbers according to the geometric distribution?

Comment: @zoli sorry, completely lost my train of thought there and was going backwards. I have come across another strange problem though with Octave's `geocdf(x, p)` function. I am inputting each randomly generated number between 0-1 as `x`, and 0.55 as `p`, but it is returning 0 for all of these. I have added my code to my post.

Comment: @zoli nevermind, I have just realised that the geocdf function is again going backwards and calculatiing the probability from k. So I am now lost with how to get the cdf in Octave so that I can get k from a random number in 0-1.

Comment: I think `geoinv` is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a discrete probability distribution $X$ which takes values on the nonnegative integers (for instance) and for which we know the values of $\Pr[X \le k]$ (the CDF) for any $k$.

Then we can sample from $X$ by generating a uniform real number $p$ from the interval $[0,1]$, and choose $k$ to be the largest value for which $p < \Pr[X \le k]$ holds. (In practice, we can do this algebraically by finding the inverse of $f(k) = \Pr[X \le k]$ and rounding, not by trial and error.)

If we do this, then $X=k$ whenever $\Pr[X \le k+1] \le p < \Pr[X \le k]$, which happens with probability $\Pr[X \le k] - \Pr[X \le k+1] = \Pr[X=k]$, so we're correctly sampling from $X$.